# create object within object dynamically

Tags: javascript

```
var json = new object();

storemap(j, "style");

function storemap(j, setobject){
    json = j;
    json['j'] = {
        json['j'].object = setobject;
    };
    return;
}
```

this is the object pattern i wanted to create.but i didt get what i need.

so i have json and i wanted to put j inisde json and then put object inside j.

so how do i create this pattern object with my function ?

```
var json = {
    j: {
        object: "style",
    }
};
```

Comment: What's the format of `setobject`?

Comment: What is `j`? Please give describing names to your variables, objects and properties.

Comment: @CapitanFindus Looks like `setobject` is a string, probably `j` is too, but who knows.

Comment: Is `new object()` just a typo or you have a function named `object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is what you want:

```
var json = {};

storemap(json, 'j', 'style');

function storemap(target, propertyName, value){
    target[propertyName] = {
        object: value
    };
}
```

or maybe this:

```
var json = storemap('j', 'style');

function storemap(propertyName, value){
    var result = {};
    result[propertyName] = {
        object: value
    };
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure I understand what you're going for, but maybe something along these lines??

```
var json = {};//creates empty object
json.j = {
    object: 'style'
};//adds property `j`, which itself is an object, containing a property called "object", with a value of 'style'
```